# Video Editing cant add background color after changing resolution

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I was editing a simple video with a resolution of 320x280. I increased the resolution a little bit(330x290) and offest the video so that it can come at the center(I wanted to add empty space at the top and sides of the video with a white background).

Now there is a transparent background. Adding color strip doesn't change the transparent background. Instead when i try changing the channel of the color strip it seems to only affect the original resolution(320x280). But i wanted to change the entire background(330x290).

[image]

Edit: Added some images for clarity.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your strip is set *Compositing > Blend >* **Alpha Over**?

[image]

If so ... you would have to share some simplyfied blend file to let us see.

Comment: No.. Ive added some images. everything else is untouched. Do u see the transparent border at the 5th image? thats the things i wanna change. but the color strip wont work. ty :)

Comment: My answer seems to be correct ... your mp4 file has to be set as "Alpha Over"  to let see strips bellow. You have set "Cross" that is why you see what you see :)

Comment: Thank u so much, i set my mp4 to "Alpha Over" and then set the color strip to "Alpha Under" and it worked. :)

Comment: If the Answer works for you consider mark it as accepted https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour .. so others can see your Question has solution from main list. Thanks to keep site organised.